# Solving inequality with Lambert W

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I'm new to the Lambert W function and need to solve an inequality in the following form **for n**:

$bcn-d\cdot (\frac{1}{a})\cdot log(1+axn)>0$

All parameters b,c,d,a and x are positive and real. 
Appreciate any help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this inequality, it first means that you need to solve for $n$ the equation
$$b c n-\frac{d }{a}\log (1+a n x)=0 \tag 1$$

I do not know why the Wipkipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)  changed quite recently. It used to contain a series of good and simple
 examples showing the steps to follow in order to arrive to something looking like $z e^z=k$ or its equivalent taking logarithms. Just trying to do it, start with $1+a n x=z$, that is to say $n=\frac{z-1}{a x}$ provided that $ax \neq 0$. So, the equation becomes 
$$b c z- dx \log(z)= b c\implies bcz-dx \log(bcz)=bc-dx \log(bc)$$ Now $bcz=u$ and just continue.

After all the required substitution steps, back to $n$, you should arrive (if I am not mistaken) to
$$n=-\frac{1}{a
   x}-\frac{d }{a b c}W\left(-\frac{b c }{d x}e^{-\frac{b c}{d x}}\right)$$ Take care that in the real domain $W(t)$ exists only if $t \geq -\frac 1e$ and that for $-\frac 1e \leq t \leq 0$, there is the other branch $W_{-1}(t)$ which is real.

**Edit**

Go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Lambert_W_function&oldid=910867451) for the examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaboration on this issue. I arrived at the same solution for the equation yesterday, however I have problems with translating this back to the inequality. Do I just substitute the = for > now or do I need to make further considerations here?

Comment: @JuB. Now, you must analyze if the function is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: $f(n)=b c n-\frac{d }{a}\log (1+a n x)=0$ is decreasing for n > 0 , which is what is of interest to me (with all parameters being positive).

Comment: The issue is that Wolfram [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bb*n%3Elog%28x*n%29%2C+n%5D)  differentiates between a vast amount of cases with a simpler form of the inequality and I am not sure how to translate this to my case.